# Delay is saving session variables on IE 11?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an application that uses an Ajax call to fetch the session variables using a PHP script. In all browsers this works perfect, but in IE 11 it does only after a page reload. So when the page loads, the Ajax call return null, but when I reload the page it does return.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ajax/fetch/session",
    success: function(data) {
        obj_fields = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj_fields);
    }
});
```

As I am using this on a multi page form when each page's values are stored in a session first, I noticed that for example when I fill in page one, submit for the next page, I need to reload to get the session. Going from page 2 to page 3, the session variables from page 1 are loaded, but the ones stored from page 2 only after a page reload. The only thing I can think of is that IE takes a while to store variables in a session.

Is this correct? How can I best fix an issue like this?

Or are returned values of Ajax calls somehow cached in IE?

I already tried with a delay of 5 seconds before doing the Ajax call, but that is also not working. Only on page reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is set to true by default, try disabling like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/ajax/fetch/session",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        obj_fields = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj_fields);
    }
});
```

> cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')
>   Type: Boolean
>   If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending "_={timestamp}" to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL that has already been requested by a GET.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score -1):

This might be issue will server machine name. Believe me
Internet Explorer seem to be a junk.

I had this experience in the past.

You will need to investigate name of the server machine. 
Internet Explorer  always has problems with machine names that has **'-' or '_' -**  or any other strange characters and with that, IE cannot easily maintain
  php session.

You will need to make sure that machine name does not have characters it does not **IE** understand. Or you can better use the server Ipaddress in place of machine name.

For instance machine name like **2_6.nancy.com** will not work but **26.nancy.com** will be okay and so on...

Comment: This was not the issue in this case as machine name is same as domain name; domain.local and domain.demo.com